# Declaring Model Definitions for use with RESTful "new" in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anyone know if there is a methodology or best practice for declaring a Model definition in the angularjs angular.module() style? I'm finding it necessary to have a skeleton model definition for the event that I go navigate to "/item/new" - that form has all sorts of bindings to the Item that comes in from a service when doing "/item/:id/edit", but there is no Item when calling new because you do not reach a service.

I know I could simply declare a global Model or a global object called "models" where I could store them myself, but I'm curious if any angular users have a better solution? I would hope for something like this:

```
angular
.module('appModels', [])
.model('item', function(){
    // Perform some operations like u would in a factory
    return {
      name: '',
      price: 0
    }
});
```

Or even more ideally:

```
    return {
      name: String,
      price: Number
    }
```

Thanks a ton

Comment: The common way to implement models in AngularJS is to use a Factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`angular.module` API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module) exposes four methods which provide subtly different implementations of this type of behaviour:

- `module.value()`
- `module.factory()`
- `module.service()`
- `module.provider()`

[This Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/56sdORWEoqg/b8hdPskxZXsJ) gives a fairly clear rundown of the use cases for all of them.

[This snippet](http://jsbin.com/ohamub/123/edit) shows all of them in action in the context of a small angular app.

I don't think I can add much to these links *vis-a-vis* the place for each of these functions with respect to each other. However, for your purpose it looks like you want to execute a 'model factory' function and receive the result of executing the function: for this purpose you probably want `module.factory()`:

```
angular
    .module('appModels', [])
    .factory('item', function(){
        return {
          name: '',
          price: 0
        }
    });
```

You can then inject this factory like so (note that the injected object is the instance returned by the factory function):

```
angular
    .module('itemController', ['appModels'])
    .controller('itemCtrl', function($scope, item) {
        console.log(item.name);
        console.log(item.price);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter - this makes complete sense, I'm just curious also if this is a common convention? I haven't seen anything like this on the web in terms of Angular examples, and I'd also like to make sure someone coming in to work behind me isn't like... "What the heck did this guy do??"

Comment: I'm not surprised that you haven't found any examples: the ecosystem of Angular examples and tutorials on the web is a bit patchy. The Google groups post that I linked in the answer is by Miško Hevery, who is one of the creators of AngularJS, so you've got a pretty authoritative source advocating this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Peter's answer is pretty good, but I had a suggestion - do not create model's module, but create a model's factory:

```
angular
.module('app', [])
.factory('appModels', function(){
    return {
        car: function (){
            return {
                name: '',
                price: 0
            };
        },
        animal: function (){
            return {
                name: '',
                kind: ''
            };
        }
    } 
});
```

In this case you will be accessing your models uses **appModels.car**, **appModels.animal**.